# SQLite - How to pass a field value to a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

My code snippet:

```
UPDATE "LookUpWrkflwTemp" SET SpiralUniverse = (
SELECT Count (*)
FROM SpiralUniverse 
WHERE Date = '2015-11-16') WHERE Date = '2015-11-16';
```

My goal is to find a Date value where the other fields in the row are null and pass that value to the above WHERE clause.

Sample data:

```
"SpiralUniverse"
rowid    Date       Symbol
1       2015-11-16   ACOR
2       2015-11-16   AAPL
3       2015-11-16   TSLA
4       2015-11-10   TSLA

"LookUpWrkflwTemp"
rowid    Date       SpiralUniverse
1       2015-11-10     1
2       2015-11-16     NULL
```

After UPDATE the result should be:

```
"LookUpWrkflwTemp"
rowid    Date       SpiralUniverse
1       2015-11-10     1
2       2015-11-16     3
```

There will only be one record in the above table where there is a date value and the other field values are null.

Comment: @golddragon007, yes that works. I´ve included this amendment to the previous question. Thank you for the working code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE LookUpWrkflwTemp
    SET SpiralUniverse = (SELECT Count(*)
                          FROM SpiralUniverse su
                          WHERE su.Date = LookUpWrkflwTemp.Date
                         )
    WHERE SprialUniverse IS NULL;
```